# Create windows Tasks programmatically using ASP.net and C# and task could not start

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2003, user-permissions

I need to create windows Tasks programmatically using ASP.net and C# (Windows Server 2003).
When I use following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "schtasks.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /create /tn MyTask /tr notepad.exe /sc DAILY /st 10:00:00 /ru myUsername /rp myPassword ";
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

It create task successfully, but task don’t execute and says “Could not start”

Also in log file it says:
"MyTask.job" (notepad.exe) 10/9/2012 10:00 PM ** ERROR **
The attempt to retrieve account information for the specified task failed; therefore, the task did not run. Either an error occurred, or no account information existed for the task.
The specific error is: 0x8004130f: No account information could be found in the Task Scheduler security database for the task indicated.

When I go through Control panel/Scheduled tasks and right click on my task and set my password again, my task will be run successfully in next time.
How can I do? 
Also when I change my code to:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "schtasks.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /create /tn MyTask /tr notepad.exe /sc DAILY /st 10:00:00 /s system /u myUsername /p myPassword ";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

It makes this error:

ERROR:  Passing the user credential on local connection

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use managed [Task Scheduler Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/), IMO it's much cleaner approach than staring a another process, even more in the case of ASP.NET application.

But if you still prefer using schtasks.exe see this SO answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/702852/351383